# Figure out who create bridge interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bridge

There is some process that create network bridges and I couldn't find who does it.
The system is Ubuntu server 20.04.2.
/etc/netplan is clean, nothing in the journalctl. What could it be ?

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-25e41661f1cf         8000.024214829968       no
br-37db19e70f2a         8000.0242c1d44e19       no
br-642c28d8a201         8000.0242a74c6849       no
br-7524b604ed26         8000.024225e214bc       no
br-7aed5e4a2a8d         8000.0242acde7f78       no
br-92d63fdfd6ef         8000.0242abdce62e       no
br-a66148fdc4f0         8000.0242e5d1b31d       no
br-aa882ec6d23f         8000.02422dd0af6b       no
br-c532eca49fcf         8000.0242fa4f24ea       no
br-dc92b8cccbae         8000.024277cbec3f       no
br-dcb490830ab5         8000.02428a24e20e       no
br-f0ebc1cdc155         8000.0242da3d005f       no
br-f69254fda7ea         8000.0242e49321e0       no
docker0         8000.024236444110       no
docker_gwbridge         8000.0242edc6b79c       no
```

Comment: don't search beyond the obvious: Docker. All of them, not just the two last. Trying to read mind: https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range

Comment: @A.B you're are savior

Comment: added an answer about this.

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like a duck...

These interfaces look like Docker managed bridge interfaces.

You can confirm this by running:

```
docker network ls
```

All the interfaces starting with `br-` will have the remainder of their name matching a network ID displayed by this command.

So I'm expecting you will find a network id `25e41661f1cf` matching `br-25e41661f1cf` etc. You can inspect its settings with `docker network inspect 25e41661f1cf` and among the JSON results you will see that it's a bridge and will see the IP address settings it received etc.

If you're concerned about the fact that with so many interfaces, you might get routing problem between your host and private networks around you (including through VPN), here's a ServerFault link on this topic:

[Configuring Docker to not use the 172.17.0.0 range](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range)

If many of these interfaces are unused, you should consider pruning. Here are Docker links on this topic:

- [docker network prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/)
- [Prune unused Docker objects](https://docs.docker.com/config)