# To finder "who" created the bridge

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

Some bridge is blocking some IP range.

```
#ifconfig
br-0674396486d8: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
```

#### I would like to understand "which process" or "who" created this bridge.

My initial suspisioucs where regarding some docker container, by `docker network ls` I didn't find are suitable network id (With name `br-<NETWORK ID>`).

The output of `brctl show br-0674396486d8`:

```
brctl show br-0674396486d8
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-0674396486d8          8000.0242545abdd4  no
```

**What else I can check ?**

#### UPDATE

After restart, the **problematic** bridge disappears, but after starting docker with **systemctl start docker**, the IP range is blocked again.

P.S.
This question is similar to:
[Figure out who create bridge interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656515/figure-out-who-create-bridge-interfaces)
but there is no a working answer for my case.

Comment: That information isn't kept with the bridge interface. So, unless you had some logging in the program which did, you can't.

Also, this is **really** the classical naming scheme for a docker bridge. This question is answered by "Yes. Docker, most likely."; this hence really *is* a duplicate of the other question, since the process would still be the docker daemon.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, For sure it comes from docker.
After restart all is fine, before I start docker.
But, how I can check to which container it's related.

Comment: You're probably putting too much effort in the wrong direction. If you have a conflict with your own internal network, then you should reconfigure Docker to never use by default these network ranges. keywords to search on Docker documentation: /etc/docker/daemon.json , `bip` , `default-address-pools`.